# Does RISC-V have equivalent set of syscall services like that of MIPS?

Tags: mips, system-calls, riscv

I know MIPS ISA out of the box has syscall instruction that can be used to print characters, open files, read from file, write to file
and [more.](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/Mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) 
This make it very easy for MIPS to be used without the need for an Operating System.

The question is, does the RISC-V ISA have an equivalent service as the above?
In other words does RISC-V provide an equivalent set services as above-out of the box?
Does one absolutely need to manually implement these syscall services on RISC-V or is it provided just like on MIPS?
e.g
On MIPS I could easily print a character using syscall instuction-I wouldn't need to implement anything to achieve this besides passing the approriate values into the appropriate registers. Can this be done on RISC-V as easily?

I hope my question was clear. Please let me know if any clarification is needed. I really appreciate the help. 
N/B
I know RISC-V has an ecall instruction but that only enables you to use system call functions which one has implemented manually.

**UPDATE**:
**Based on the comments I now understand that syscall and ecall are the instructions provided by MIPS and RISCV respectively. The ISA doesn't specify what should happen beyond these calls. In order words the functionalities provided after these calls are dictated by the operating environment.**

Comment: I think it's important to note that MIPS isn't providing these function as part of it's ISA but instead popular simulators are providing them as hooks into the `syscall` instruction. This instruction really just triggers a software exception designed to allow an operating system to take over and do something based on the registers. RISCV has a similar instruction, `ecall` (formerly `scall`)

Comment: @Unn so on an actual MIPS core you would need to manually implement handlers for these syscall ?

Comment: Yes, we need to keep the concept of operating environments and the processors' instruction set architectures separate -- MARS that you're quoting (and it RISC V equivalent RARS) offer both instruction set simulation and nominal operating environments that provide some OS-like functionality.

Comment: However, the instruction set architectures for MIPS & RISC V specify only the instruction themselves, `syscall` and `ecall`. but do not say what they should do beyond making a request of the operating environment.  Different operating environments, like linux, will provide different offerings than the MARS/RARS operating environments, as may embedded operating systems like zephyr.

Comment: @ErikEidt I see it all making sense now thanks.

Comment: This makes me wonder what happens when you use `syscall` on a PlayStation or N64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, in the version of the MARS simulator for RISC V, called [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars):

- https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars/wiki/Environment-Calls

These `ecall`s in RARS are the same as the ones in MARS, but with a few new ones added.

RARS uses `a7` for selecting call number, whereas MARS uses `$v0`.

Let's also note that for both MARS and RARS the system calls are incomplete and not orthogonal.  For example, you can print an integer to the console but not to a file.

Still, this group of system calls allows for simpler programs than linux would, since on linux all we really have is character I/O; so, printing a integer even to the console requires `itoa` capability in the user's program.